# copy constructor not called, can someone explain how returnin values from function works

Tags: c++, c++11, return, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No call to the copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173632/no-call-to-the-copy-constructor)

In this code copy constructor is never called (neither does move constructor, or assignment operator). How it is possible? Can someone explain how function returns values, what happens with stack and registers (or post some good link)?

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Test;

Test getnew(int arg);
class Test
{

  public:
    char *conts;
    int len;
        Test(char* input = NULL){conts = new char[len=10];
            if(input)strncpy(conts,input,9);else strcpy(conts,"xxxxx");
            cout << "\nconstructor: " << conts;
        };
        Test(const Test& t){
                conts = new char[10];
                if(t.len)strncpy(conts,t.conts,9);
                len = t.len;
                cout << "\ncopy-constructor: " << conts;
        };
        Test(Test&& t){
               conts = t.conts;
               t.conts = NULL;
               std::swap(len,t.len);
               cout << "\nmove-constructor: " << conts;
        };

        ~Test(){
            cout << "\ndestructor";
            if(conts)delete [] conts;
             len = 0;
             conts = NULL;
        };
        Test& operator=(Test rhs)
        {
            std::swap(conts,rhs.conts);
            std::swap(len,rhs.len);
            cout << "\nassigend: " << conts;
        }

};

int main()
{

   Test t2 = getnew(1);
   cout << endl << t2.conts;
    return 0;
}

Test getnew(int arg)
{
        Test retj("FFFFF");
        return retj;
}
```

Only one constructor and one destructor is called. But object t2 has value member conts initialized with correct value "FFFF". I know that return value optimizations are applied, but how object t2 is initialized?

Comment: What do you mean, "how"?

Comment: I mean - what happens behind the scene :)

Comment: Quick simplified explanation on how many ABIs handle functions that return "complicated" classes by value. The caller is responsible for providing some space where that return value will exist. It then passes a pointer as an extra argument to the function. The function constructs its return value at the address given by the extra argument. So inside getnew, the compiler has all the information and can create retj directly at that return address, skipping the copy.

Comment: Just like "this" pointer for member function? OK, if this is true, I'm satisfied with this answer for now, but still if there is some good article about how returning value from function works it would be good. Especially in case of f( g() ), how g() returns value and passes it to f() directly?

Comment: h (the function that calls `f(g())`) reserves some space for that temporary, passes a pointer to that space to g so it can construct its return value there, and passes the same pointer to f so it can read the value. Nothing hard there. Notice that the same thing happens whether f takes the argument by value or const&, except that by value you get something non-const, hence the recommendation you can read sometimes of taking some arguments by value.

Comment: OK thank you. I could ask many more questions, but for now it's OK. Do You know where I could find some resources about this topic?

Answer (score 4):

*In theory*, what should happen is that the compiler creates a temporary copy of your return value and that temporary object is then assigned to the variable which receives the output of the function.

However, the compiler is allowed to elide copies and moves of a returned value even though the copy constructor or move constructor has side-effects. In your case, this turns into a so-called **NRVO** (Named Return Value Optimization), which is a special case of **RVO** (Return Value Optimization).

Thus, it is very likely that what you are seeing is a result of a move elision. There are compiler options to disable this optimization, but some compilers (e.g. Clang 3.2) have bugs handling those options (see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297639/rvalue-hello-world-missing-constructor/14298095#14298095)).

Comment: Mentioning *"**accessible** copy-constructor/move-constructor is still needed for **semantic check**, even though the compiler doesn't really invoked them, otherwise the code is ill-formed"* would be a good idea.

Comment: @Nawaz: good point, I agree it is relevant, but I think the question was more focused on what happens when the code *does* compile.

Comment: yes, that's what I want to know. I know that compiler tends not to call copy or move constructor if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), `T2` is assigned to the `Test` object initialized in `getnew`. That's how RVO works.

Comment: I think I already wrote that I know that :) But what exactly happens? And how does returning of the value work?

Comment: Are you asking what happens on the assembly level? I'm not sure off the top of my head. The important point in RVO is that a copy/move constructor isn't called.

Comment: t2 and retj will be the same object (same address).

Comment: Test getnew(int) is likely implemented the same as void getnew(Test*, int).

Comment: Yes, if possible I would like to know what happens on assembly level. Does compiler pushes address of t2 to the stack in place where retj should be? Any external link on how returning values work would be good. I understand basic of assembly, so I should be able to understand such explanations.